# can we pass unsigned char to inet_ntop()

Tags: c, networking, inet-ntop

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

char buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
int af = AF_INET;
unsigned char addr[4] = {0x7f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1};

printf("Address: %s\n", inet_ntop(af, addr, buf, sizeof buf));
```

Is it valid to pass `unsigned char` array to `inet_ntop()` call? The code above works, but the man page says API expects network address structure in the second argument.

Comment: Useful ref [INET_NTOP(3)              Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html)

Comment: Mark, Any particular reason for not using `struct in_addr addr`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, it is legacy code, I would not like to make massive changes :)

Comment: If its legacy code and one is using the same legacy  compiler, options, OS, you are OK - else I suspect you are [SOL](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit%20outta%20luck).

Answer (score 0):

I see that [one implementation uses](https://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/sockaddr_inman.html) `unsigned long`  as the  one member of `struct in_addr addr`.   If you compile on a system where `unsigned long` is not 4 bytes - I could foresee trouble.  If a system have stricter alignment requirements for `struct in_addr` than `char []`, again I could foresee trouble.

In the end, it seems you are looking for assurance that this weak code will be OK going forward.  I wish you luck.